# Ping IP returned "destination net unreachable", even with different network

Tags: routing, internet

I couldn't log in to facebook, so I ping the domain and got this:

> ping www.facebook.com
>
> Pinging www.facebook.com [69.171.228.14] with 32 bytes of data:
>
> Request timed out.
>
> Reply from 204.15.23.57: Destination net unreachable.

But when I ping this IP, it is reachable.

> Pinging 204.15.23.57 with 32 bytes of data:
>
> Reply from 204.15.23.57: bytes=32 time=190ms TTL=51

I realize it is something wrong with my computer, as I have tried using different networks (on the same network other devices can connect to facebook), resetting router's routing table, clear my computer arp cache...but none of it works.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is question is not about network engineering as defined in the ["On Topic" guidelines](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  Have you seen [SU]?  It is geared more towards these types of questions.

Answer (score 2):

What it means is that a host with the IP 204.15.23.57 does not have a route to 69.171.228.14. So 204.15.23.57 is telling you that the destination network is unreachable.

The IP 204.15.23.57 resolves to ae0.dr05.prn1.tfbnw.net and tfbnw.net is "The FaceBook NetWork".

Try running a trace route to either of those addresses to learn more.